# How to show a picture when hover a link (mouseover/mouseout)?

Tags: javascript, mouseover, mouseout

I am trying to get a link to show a box with a picture in it, with `mouseover` and `mouseout`. I have tried an array, but couldn't get any result out of that and right now, this is the code I have (which gives me the same result as the array).

I get the image to show, but I only get the first one, for all links.  I got the same result when I used an array (that all links shows a pic, but only the first pic), but I guess I just fail to connect the right picture with the right link.

Can someone please help me with this?

```
<p id="lankar"><a href="#" alt="site1" />Link 1</p>
<p id="link" class="hide"><img src="img/bild1.jpg"></p>

<p id="lankar1"><a href="#" alt="site2" />Link 2</p>
<p id="link1" class="hide"><img src="img/bild2.jpg"></p>

<p id="lankar2"><a href="#" alt="site3" />link 3</p>
<p id="link2" class="hide"><img src="img/bild3.jpg"></p>

<script>
var links = document.getElementById('lankar');
links.addEventListener("mouseover", showBox);
links.addEventListener("mouseout", hideBox);
var links1 = document.getElementById('lankar1');
links1.addEventListener("mouseover", showBox);
links1.addEventListener("mouseout", hideBox);
var links2 = document.getElementById('lankar2');
links2.addEventListener("mouseover", showBox);
links2.addEventListener("mouseout", hideBox);

function showBox() {
if(document.getElementById('lankar'))
document.getElementById('link').style.display = 'block';
else if(document.getElementById('lankar1'))
document.getElementById('link1').style.display = 'block';
else if(document.getElementById('lankar2'))
document.getElementById('link2').style.display = 'block';
}


function hideBox() {
if(document.getElementById('lankar'))
document.getElementById('link').style.display = 'none';
else if(document.getElementById('lankar1'))
document.getElementById('link1').style.display = 'none';
else if(document.getElementById('lankar2'))
document.getElementById('link2').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: In your `if/else` blocks the first `if` condition is *always* true.  You're basically just checking if an element by that `id` exists, and it always does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS `:hover` ... and drop a few markup's

```css
.lankar {
  display: block
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.lankar:hover + .hide, .hide:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="lankar" href="#" alt="site1">Link 1</a>
<img class="hide" src="http://placehold.it/150x100/00f">

<a class="lankar" href="#" alt="site1">Link 2</a>
<img class="hide" src="http://placehold.it/150x100/0f0">

<a class="lankar" href="#" alt="site1">Link 3</a>
<img class="hide" src="http://placehold.it/150x100/f00">
```

Comment: Thanks! That was actually much better than I hoped for! I dont know why I always has to make things so difficult, when its obviously not. Hopefully i will learn when I get better at this. ;)

Comment: @Isla Yes you will ... and as you can see, I did :)